# Unexpected result with recursive glob.glob using '**' pattern

Tags: python, glob

Recursive glob result on non-existing directory:

```py
>>> import os, glob
>>> os.path.exists('dir')
False

>>> glob.glob('dir/*', recursive=True)
[]

>>> glob.glob('dir/**', recursive=True)
['dir/']
```

Recursive glob result on existing file returned as directory:

```py
>>> os.path.exists('file')
True

>>> glob.glob('file/*', recursive=True)
[]

>>> glob.glob('file/**', recursive=True)
['file/']
```

Similar commands with bash shell completion would produce following output:

```bash
$ shopt -s globstar failglob

$ ls dir
ls: cannot access 'dir': No such file or directory
$ echo dir/*
-bash: no match: dir/*
$ echo dir/**
-bash: no match: dir/**

$ touch file
$ echo file/*
-bash: no match: file/*
$ echo file/**
-bash: no match: file/**
```

Is there any logical explanation on glob results returned with '**' pattern or just a bug?

Comment: Just a bug, obviously.

Comment: A [bug report](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/79382) for issue was filed in 2018.